# Count Total Number of XmlNodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find a way to get the total number of child nodes from an XmlNode recursively.

That it is to say I want to count all the children, grand children etc.

I think its something like

```
node.SelectNodes(<fill in here>).Count
```

but I don't know what the XPath is.

Comment: Without seeing a sample of your XML, we can't figure out the XPath either!

The approach is correct though.

Comment: Why do you need to see my XML as I'm wanting to count all nodes irrespective of name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XPath supports something called [Axis specifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath_1.0#Axis_specifiers), so the code you're looking for is

```
node.SelectNodes("descendant::*").Count
```

Answer (score 4):

**The XPath you are after is**:

**`descendant::node()`**   (1)

or

**`descendant::*`**   (2)

The first XPath expresion (1) above selects any node (text-node, processing-instruction, comment, element) in the subtree rooted by the current node.

(2) selects any element node in the subtree rooted by the current node.

Comment: (2) is equivalent to `descendant-or-self::*`, but the question was only for the child nodes, not including the current node (of course, it's just a matter of subtracting 1)

Comment: This is also correct! but he needs the points more than you :S

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

node.DescendantNodes().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing an *unfiltered* count, which your question implies, you could just traverse the them using the `ChildNodes` property:

```
private int CountChildren(XmlNode node)
{
   int total = 0;

   foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
   {
      total++;
      total += CountChildren(child);
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: @Steve Danner, @Kevin yes I know I can do it recursively, just presumed there would be an xpath way

Answer (score 0):

You could use somthing like this:

```
private static int CountNodes(XmlNode node)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        count += CountNodes(childNode);
    }

    return count + node.ChildNodes.Count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do it for you though not through xPath:

```
void CountNode(XmlNode node, ref int count)
{
    count += node.ChildNodes.Count;

    foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        CountNode(child, ref count);
    }
}
```

For reference here is a link to the count function in xpath.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103.aspx

so if you were looking for all the same type of nodes you could do

```
//Your_node
```

to select all the nodes

```
//*
```

Comment: `descendant::Your_Node` selects all nodes *called* `Your_Node` below the current node