# Number of Nodes with XPathDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to count all the nodes within an xml document using XPathDocument

the code im using is

```
var xmlPathDoc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
XPathNavigator documentNav = xmlPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
```

is there a way to count these when i dont know the name of the nodes

i wanted to use something like

```
int nodeCount = documentNav.Select("/").Count;
```

but wasnt sure what to put in the select part

thanks

simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XmlNode node = myDoc.SelectSingleNode("/");

int i = node.SelectNodes("descendant::*").Count;
```

Also refer [Count Total Number of XmlNodes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645319/count-total-number-of-xmlnodes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`XDocument.Descendents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) and count them:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var count = doc.Descendants().Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need XPath. First get the DOM object and get the nodelist of all elements and get its count.

```
public virtual XmlNodeList GetElementsByTagName(String tagname )


    Returns a NodeList of all the Elements with a given tag name in the order 
    in which they are encountered in a preorder traversal of the Document tree.

        Parameters:
            tagname - The name of the tag to match on. The special value "*"
            matches all tags. 
        Returns:
            A new NodeList object containing all the matched Elements.
```